# What to try to solve an integral $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\pi} e^{x(\sin(x))^k}dx$?

Tags: integration

What to try to solve an integral $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^{\pi} e^{x(\sin(x))^k}dx$, similar?

Change of variables to $e^u$ and use theorem?

Series expansions? Sound complicated.

Some assumption about $[0, \pi]$ and trigonometric functions?

Comment: Lebesgue's theorem on dominated convergence!

Comment: @Jochen Okay, but I don't understand how to figure out where that converges.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_k(x):= e^{x (\sin (x))^k}$ for $x \in [0, \pi].$

We have $f_k(x)  \to 1$ as $k \to \infty $ for all $x \in [0, \pi], x \ne \pi/2$

and

$f_k( \pi/2)=e^{\pi/2}$ for all $k$.

Now invoke Lebesgue's theorem .

Comment: Also, why does it go to $1$?

Comment: For $x \in [0, \pi], x \ne \pi/2$ we have $0 \le \sin(x) <1.$ Hence $( \sin(x))^k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$, Therfore $f_k(x) \to e^0=1.$